# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^1 [x^n + (1-x)^n ]^{1/n} \ \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

> **Evaluate**
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^1 [x^n + (1-x)^n ]^{1/n} \ \mathrm{d}x$$

I simplified the limit to

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1/2} \left[\left(\frac{1}{2}+x\right)^n + \left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)^n \right]^{1/n} \ \mathrm{d}x$$

using properties of definite integrals, but I can't solve further.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: 1 Fractional part is redundant here. 2 Apply dominated convergence theorem 3 Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a^n+b^n)^{1/n}=\max(a,b)$ for positive $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Norbert Sorry Sir, but I haven't read about Dominated convergence theorem yet.

Comment: Then you have the DCT to look forward to, since it makes your problem easy.  Perhaps the integrand converges uniformly to $\max(a,b)$, so the Riemann theory of integration will work.

Comment: @GEdgar This was 5 years ago. I have since read about DCT and much more :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint: It looks like there may be a mistake in your proposed simplification step, but at any rate, you can break the limit up into $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{1/2} f_n dx + \int_{1/2}^1 f_n dx$ where $f_n = (x^n + (1 - x)^n)^{1/n}$. You should be able to show that in each piece of the broken up integral, either $x^n$ is hugely dominating or $(1-x)^n$ is hugely dominating (before you take the root). Since then you are taking the $n$th root before integrating, this will hopefully allow you to see what the limit should be.

Comment: If either is dominating, does that mean we can ignore the other term? Which theorem is that?

Comment: I edited my simplification step. Now it's correct.

Comment: @Samurai Sorry, my hint was not necessarily directly appealing to any classical theorems that can simply be applied directly. However, if you understand the proof outline, filling in the details shouldn't be too hard hopefully, even if you make minimal use of theorems. I'm not sure what theorems are available to you now so it would be hard to put it in terms of theorems you are allowed to use (plus I would have to look up analysis/calculus theorems to know the easiest way to phrase this argument in terms of those most common theorems).

Answer (score 4):

Note that for $1\ge x>1/2$,

$$xe^{\frac1n \left(\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)^n-\frac12\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)^{2n}\right)}<\left(x^n+(1-x)^n\right)^{1/n}=x\left(1+\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)^n\right)^{1/n}<xe^{\frac1n \left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)^n}$$

where we used the estimates $x-\frac12 x^2<\log (1+x)<x$.  Thus, by the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem#Statement)

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(x^n+(1-x)^n\right)^{1/n}=x \tag 1$$

for $1\ge x>1/2$.  Exploiting symmetry, we have for $0\le x<1/2$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(x^n+(1-x)^n\right)^{1/n}=1-x \tag 2$$

Therefore, putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together reveals

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(x^n+(1-x)^n\right)^{1/n}=\frac12 +\left|x-\frac12\right|$$

And since $1/2<\left(x^n+(1-x)^n\right)^{1/n}\le 1$, we can use the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) to obtain

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 \left(x^n+(1-x)^n\right)^{1/n}\,dx&=\int_0^1 \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(x^n+(1-x)^n\right)^{1/n}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \left( \frac12 +\left| x-\frac12 \right| \right) \,dx\\\\
&=\frac34
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: (+1) However, on $\left[\frac12,1\right]$, note that $\left[1+\left(\frac{1-x}x\right)^n\right]^{1/n}\le2$ and easily $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left[1+\left(\frac{1-x}x\right)^n\right]^{1/n}=1$. From these observations alone, we can apply Dominated Convergence.

Comment: @robjohn First of all, thank you!  Second, the development before validating the interchange of limit and integral was to establish that the limit of the integrand was $1/2+|x-1/2|$.  Then, the estimate $1/2<(x^n+(1-x)^n)^{1/n}\le 1$ alone permitted use of the DCT.  Did I misunderstand your note?  Or was my answer unclear?

Answer (score 2):

It's a little easier to let $x=(1+u)/2$ with $-1\le u\le1$. We have

$$\int_0^1(x^n+(1-x)^n)^{1/n}dx={1\over2}\int_{-1}^1\left(\left(1+u\over2\right)^n+\left(1-u\over2\right)^n \right)^{1/n}du=\int_0^1\left(1+u\over2\right)\left(1+\left(1-u\over1+u\right)^n \right)^{1/n}du$$

where we did two things in the second step: we used the symmetry between $1+u$ and $1-u$ to replace ${1\over2}\int_{-1}^1$ with $\int_0^1$, and we factored out the $\left(1+u\over2\right)^n$.  What you do from here on out depends in part on how finicky you need to be about moving the limit across the integral sign. But since for $0\le u\le1$ we have

$$1\le\left(1+\left(1-u\over1+u\right)^n \right)^{1/n}\le\left(1+\left(1-0\over1+0\right)^n \right)^{1/n}=2^{1/n}$$

we see that

$$\int_0^1\left(1+u\over2\right)du\le\int_0^1\left(1+u\over2\right)\left(1+\left(1-u\over1+u\right)^n \right)^{1/n}du\le2^{1/n}\int_0^1\left(1+u\over2\right)du\to\int_0^1\left(1+u\over2\right)du$$

so the Squeeze Theorem tell us

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1(x^n+(1-x)^n)^{1/n}dx=\int_0^1\left(1+u\over2\right)du={(1+u)^2\over4}\big|_0^1=1-{1\over4}={3\over4}$$

Answer (score -1):

$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1(x^n+(1-x)^n)^{1/n}\ dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1x(1+((1-x)/x)^n)^{1/n}dx$. Now $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+(1-x)/x)ⁿ)^{1/n}=1$. This can be verified by taking log. Assuming uniform convergence we get the result as $\int_0^1xdx=1/2.$

Comment: That is not the correct answer unfortunately.