# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \,dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I have the following limit to find:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx$$

And I have to choose between the following options:

**A.** $0$

**B.** $1$

**C.** $\dfrac{3}{4}$

**D.** $\dfrac{1}{2}$

**E.** $\dfrac{1}{4}$

This is what I did:

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n}  \, dx =
\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx +
\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx$$

- If we consider the first term of this sum:

$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx \ge
\int_0^\frac{1}{2} \sqrt[n]{x^n+x^n} \, dx =
\int_0^\frac{1}{2}2^{\frac{1}{n}}x \, dx$$

And that means:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx \ge
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\frac{1}{2}2^{\frac{1}{n}}x \, dx =
\int_0^\frac{1}{2}x \, dx = 
\frac{1}{8} \tag 1$$

- If we consider the second term of that sum we have:

$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx \ge
\int_\frac{1}{2}^1 \sqrt[n]{(1-x)^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx =
\int_\frac{1}{2}^1 2^{\frac{1}{n}}(1-x) \, dx$$

And that means:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx \ge \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\frac{1}{2}^1 2^{\frac{1}{n}}(1-x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\frac{1}{2}^1 (1-x) \, dx = \frac{1}{8} \tag 2$$

Now we can sum $(1)$ and $(2)$ and we have:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx \ge \frac{1}{4}$$

So now we have a lower bound. We can do something similar for the upper bound.

- Again, let's consider the first term of that sum:

$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx \le
\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt[n]{(1-x)^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx = 
\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} 2^\frac{1}{n}(1-x) \, dx$$

That means:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx \le
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} 2^\frac{1}{n}(1-x) \, dx = 
\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} (1-x) \, dx = 
\frac{3}{8} \tag 3$$

- And if we consider the second part of that sum:

$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx \le 
\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+x^n} \, dx = 
\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 2^\frac{1}{n} x \, dx$$

And that means:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx \le
\lim\_{n \to \infty} \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 2^\frac{1}{n} x \, dx = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 x \, dx = 
\frac{3}{8} \tag 4$$

And now if we sum $(3)$ and $(4)$ we get:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx \le
\frac{3}{4}$$

So after all of that, we have:

$$\frac{1}{4} \le
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \, dx \le \frac{3}{4}$$

But this didn't help me all that much. Choices **C**, **D** and **E** are still consistent with this inequality that I got. So what should I do to find the exact answer? Or did I do something wrong in my calculations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^1 [x^n + (1-x)^n ]^{1/n} \ \mathrm{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379321/evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-int-01-xn-1-xn-1-n-mathrmdx). This might also me helpful: https://ysharificalc.wordpress.com/2018/03/18/limit-of-integrals-9/ as it's quite nicely done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The present problem is proposed by Prof. **Ovidiu Furdui** and appeared in **Teme de analiza matematica**. The solution presented is straightforward (using Squeeze theorem)

$$\small\frac{3}{4}=\int_0^{1/2}(1-x)\textrm{d}x+\int_{1/2}^1 x \textrm{d}x\le I_n \le \int_0^{1/2} \sqrt[n]{(1-x)^n+(1-x)^n}\textrm{d}x +\int_{1/2}^1\sqrt[n]{x^n+x^n}\textrm{d}x=\frac{3}{4}\sqrt[n]{2},$$

where the integral under the limit is denoted by $I_n$.

Letting $n\to\infty$ the desired limit follows, that is $3/4$.

**More information:** If interested in limits with such a structure, you may consult the book **Limits, Series, and Fractional Part Integrals
Problems in Mathematical Analysis by Ovidiu Furdui.**

For example, on page $7$ you may find the trigonometric version

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt[n]{\sin^n(x)+\cos^n(x)}\textrm{d}x,$$

which leads to $\sqrt{2}$ and that can be finished by a similar strategy.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you ge the first inequality? I understand the second one, but why is it that $I_n \ge \displaystyle\int_0^{1 / 2} (1 - x) dx + \displaystyle\int_{1/2} ^ 1 x dx$?

Comment: @user1502 If you look at the original integral under the limit and split the integral at $x=1/2$, then you get the desired inequality by taking out one of the terms under the radical for each of the two integrals. For example, $$\int_0^{1/2}(1-x) \textrm{d}x=\int_0^{1/2} \sqrt[n]{(1-x)^n} \textrm{d}x \le \int_0^{1/2} \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n} \textrm{d}x.$$ You proceed in a similar style for the other integral from $x=1/2$ to $x=1$. Is it all now crystal clear?

Comment: It's clear now. Thanks a lot for taking the time.

Answer (score 2):

Let the integrand be $f(x)$. Obviously $f(0)=f(1)=1$ and the function achieves a single minimum $\left(\frac12,\frac{\sqrt[n]2}2\right)$. Hence we have certainly $\frac12<I_n<1$.

---

If you want to compute the limit anyway,

$$\sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n}dx=x\sqrt[n]{1+\left(\frac{1-x}x\right)^n}\to x$$ when $1-x<x$, and symmetrically. Hence the limit function is simply

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}x\le\frac12\to1-x,\\x\ge\frac12\to x\end{cases}$$ and the area under it is $\frac34$.

---

Plot for $n=15$:

[image]

---

**Update:**

The initial argument is wrong, as it only proves $$\frac12\le I\le 1.$$

For a better proof, observe that for all $x$, $$\sqrt{x^2+(1-x)^2}\ge f(x)\ge\max(1-x,x),$$ which excludes $\frac12$ and $1$.